# How to ignore event source log

Tags: nginx, logging, regex, fail2ban

I have an event source running regularly. The problem is that `http-get-dos` from fail2ban will catch the IP if the user left the tab open for a large amount of time.

So , I am thinking, how can I disable this type of specific log in ningx? The alternative is to configure fail2ban to ignore this pattern.

```
"GET /users/stream HTTP/2.0"
```

I am willing to implement in nginx or fail2ban.

Probably changing accordingly this line in  `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/http-get-dos.conf`    is the most straightforward way:

```
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*
```

**Update** (/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/http-get-dos.conf):

```
# Fail2Ban configuration file
[Definition]

# Option: failregex
# Note: This regex will match any GET entry in your logs, so basically all valid and not valid entries are a match.
# You should set up in the jail.conf file, the maxretry and findtime carefully in order to avoid false positives.
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*
# Option: ignoreregex
ignoreregex =
```

---

```
##To stop DOS attack from remote host.
[http-get-dos]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = http-get-dos
logpath  = /usr/local/nginx/localhost-access.log
maxretry = 300
findtime = 300
bantime = 600
action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
```

**First try:** Apparently not working with the regex below:

```
fail2ban-regex /usr/local/nginx/localhost-access.log '^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*' '^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"(GET) /users/stream.*$'

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex line : ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*
Use ignoreregex line : ^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"(GET) /users/stream.*$
Use         log file : /usr/local/nginx/localhost-access.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 22431 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [22431] ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total
```

**Second try:** But will work with `^<HOST> -.*"(GET) /users/stream.*$`

```
fail2ban-regex /usr/local/nginx/localhost-access.log '^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*' '^<HOST> -.*"(GET) /users/stream.*$'

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex line : ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*
Use ignoreregex line : ^<HOST> -.*"(GET) /users/stream.*$
Use         log file : /usr/local/nginx/localhost-access.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 1574 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [1574] ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*
`-

Ignoreregex: 22093 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [22093] ^<HOST> -.*"(GET) /users/stream.*$
`-
```

Comment: You know that you can also ignore IP addresses?

Comment: @sebix how does that help?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question

Comment: `http-get-dos` is not a filter shipped with fail2ban. You'll need to include a copy of your configuration in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track using the

```
ignoreregex =
```

directive in your

```
/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/http-get-dos.conf
```

config file. This should just be a matter of tweaking the regex. Something like this:

```
^<HOST> -.*"(GET) /users/stream.*$
```

which matches your log file line, then matches for any GET's and only GET's with requests that have the /users/stream prefix, and any string appended to it.

Comment: It will work with `^<HOST> -.*"(GET) /users/stream.*$`

Comment: Thanks, edited regex in the answer to match the working version.